# How to force Fake.app to connect an HTML element by XPath (instead of "id" attribute)

Tags: fake.app

I want to "connect" a Fake Action to an HTML Element on the page via **XPath**, but when I try to connect the Element, the Element is specified by HTML `id` attribute instead.

How do I force Fake to specify an HTML Element by XPath when "connecting"?

Answer (score 2):

Developer of [Fake](http://fakeapp.com) here.

First, make sure you understand the [concept of "Connecting" in Fake](http://vimeo.com/14701789).

Fake allows you to *specify* an HTML Element via one of several methods:

1. HTML `id` attribute
2. HTML `name` attribute
3. CSS Selector
4. XPath Expression
5. arbitrary JavaScript Expression

**Connecting** is an **automatic** way to *specify* an Element. Fake can only *connect* an Element using one of two methods:

1. HTML `id` attribute
2. XPath Expression

If you want to specify via one of the other methods you must do so *"by hand"*.

When you *connect* an Action to an HTML Element, Fake will first try to *specify* the connected Element using the **HTML `id` attribute**. If that is not possible (becuase the Element has no `id` attribute), Fake will try to specify the connected Element using **XPath**.

**Via `id`** is the default because it is efficient and easily understandable.

**Via XPath** is the fallback because it is always possible, but less efficent and less easliy understandable.

---

However, there are times when you might prefer to *connect* an Action to an Element, but *specify* the Element via XPath instead of `id`. This is possible via the steps below:

1. First add a connectable Action (like `Set Value of HTML Element`) to your Workflow.
2. *Before* connecting, change the *specifier type* to `for XPath`.
3. Then connect as normal. Hold the control key (`⌃`) while dragging from the Action to an Element on the page.

The Element will now be specified via XPath, instead of `id`.

[image]
[image]